# continuous and monotonic function

Tags: continuity

If there is a function that

1. continuous in a interval
2. monotonic in the same interval

Does it mean the function is also differentiation function in the interval?

Comment: Look at $f(x)=\cases{ x, &$x<1$\cr 2x-1, &$x\ge 1$}$     on the interval $(0,2)$.

Answer (score 2):

By Lebesgue differentiation theorem, every monotonic function is almost everywhere differentiable.

However, we cannot replace "almost everywhere" with "everywhere": just consider $f(x)=x+\frac{1}{2}|x|$ in $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

No. There exists functions that are continuous on an interval, but differentiable nowhere. See details in [Wikipedia: Weierstraß function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function).

If the function is also monotonic, a non-trivial theorem states that a monotonic function is differentiable, except perhaps on a subset of measure $0$. See [Monotonic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function).

If you read French, you can see a proof that uses the [Rising Sun Lemma here](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemme_du_soleil_levant).

Comment: Oops! I forgot that point. I've completed my answer.